# How to get pyqtgraph to recognize unix milisecond timestamp as x axis?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, unix-timestamp, pyqtgraph

I'm finally getting towards the end (sort of) of a two month long effort to replicate a candlestick chart in PyQt5.
Other than the annoyance of setting proper view bounds for scrolling I need to more importantly configure the chart to display dates and times rather than 0,1,2,3,4,ect at the bottom.
I obtain the data from MT5's python API.

The unix time is an integer datatype and the price is a float datatype unfortunately, so I had to get slightly creative with my arrays.

I'm using pure numpy arrays since pandas is relatively much slower and I want to avoid structured arrays for the same reason so I added the unix time for each bar in a separate array with the same index numbers as the arrays with price.
If there's a better way, let me know.

My current issue is that the pyqtgraph plot does not recognize the data when I apply

```
axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
plt.setAxisItems({"bottom": axis})
```

The documentation is lacking so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm assuming it might have something to do with the 'width' parameter in the CandlestickItem class since I don't think it is converted into datetime yet but I have no idea what to do about that if that is the case.
The documentation says that it takes a unix timestamp but it just loads an empty plot.

I'm having issues finding any examples on the web that can help me.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import time
import threading
import os
import queue
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import math

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'''chart items'''


class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):

    _boundingRect = QtCore.QRectF()

    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        self.flagHasData = False
        
        

    def set_data(self, *data):
        self.old_data, self.current_data, self.time_data = data
        self.flagHasData = True
        self.generatePicture()
        self.informViewBoundsChanged()
        


    def generatePicture(self):
        
# update previous candles

        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        width = (self.time_data[1] - self.time_data[0] / 3)

        for (number, open, close) in self.old_data:
            time = self.time_data[len(self.old_data)-1]
            rect = QtCore.QRectF(time - width, open, width * 2, close - open)
            path.addRect(rect)
            # print(rect)

            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(rect)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# update currently active candle
        path2 = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    
        for (number, open, close) in self.current_data[[len(self.current_data)-1]]:
            time = self.time_data[len(self.old_data)-1]
            rect2 = QtCore.QRectF(time - width, open, width * 2, close - open)
            path2.addRect(rect2)
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(rect2)
        p.end()
        self._boundingRect = path.boundingRect()

    def paint(self, p, *args):

        if self.flagHasData:
            p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)
  
            
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._boundingRect

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# establish connection to the MetaTrader 5 terminal
if not mt5.initialize():
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
    quit()

# attempt to enable the display of the EURUSD in MarketWatch
selected = mt5.symbol_select("EURUSD", True)
if not selected:
    print("Failed to select EURUSD")
    mt5.shutdown()
    quit()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------



class Candle_type_handler:
#loads arrays and threads
    def __init__(self, func_list=None, *args):
        self.tick_counter = 1
        self.bar_counter = 1
        self.last_tick = 0
        self.last_bar = 0
        self.current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")
        self.open_value = self.current_tick[1]
        
        self.chart_array = np.zeros((100000, 3), dtype=float)
        self.chart_array[0, 1] = self.current_tick[1]
        self.chart_array[0, 2] = self.current_tick[1]
        self.chart_array[1, 1] = self.current_tick[1]
        self.chart_array[1, 2] = self.current_tick[1]

        self.candle_array = np.zeros((100000, 3), dtype=float)
        self.candle_array[0, 1] = self.current_tick[1]
        self.candle_array[0, 2] = self.current_tick[1]
    
        self.tick_timestamp = np.zeros((100000, 1), dtype= np.int64)
        self.tick_timestamp[0] = self.current_tick[5]
        self.tick_timestamp[1] = self.current_tick[5]
        
        self.last_old_candle_data = self.chart_array[:2]
        self.last_new_candle_data = self.candle_array[:2]
        self.last_time_data = self.tick_timestamp[:2]
        
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.update_newest_ticks, args=())
        t1.start()
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.timer, args=())
        t2.start()
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.update_chart, args=())
        t3.start()



    
    def timer(self):
    #waits 30 seconds before loading a new bar

        time.sleep(30)
        self.update_candle()
        
        self.timer()

    def update_newest_ticks(self, *args):
    #handles data for the current active bar

        last_bar = 0
        current_bar = 0
        open_value = 0
        current_tick = 0

        self.current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")

        while True:
            self.current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")
            
            #if tick value has changed update the array and put values into queue
            if self.last_tick != self.current_tick:
                self.last_tick = self.current_tick
                # self.tick_timestamp[self.tick_counter] = self.current_tick[5]
                self.candle_array[self.tick_counter, 0], self.candle_array[self.tick_counter, 1], self.candle_array[self.tick_counter, 2] = self.bar_counter , self.open_value, self.current_tick[1]
                self.tick_counter += 1
                newtick.put(self.candle_array[:self.tick_counter])



            else:
                pass

    def update_candle(self):
    #handles data for all of the previous bars

        self.current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")
        self.tick_timestamp[self.bar_counter] = self.current_tick[5]
        self.chart_array[self.bar_counter, 0], self.chart_array[self.bar_counter, 1], self.chart_array[self.bar_counter, 2] = self.bar_counter, self.chart_array[self.bar_counter - 1, 2], self.current_tick[1]
        self.bar_counter += 1
        self.open_value = self.current_tick[1]
        newbar.put([self.chart_array[:self.bar_counter], self.tick_timestamp[:self.bar_counter]])


    def update_chart(self):
    #pushes bar and tick data into the plot

        while True:
            
            #check if queues are empty, if not use current data, if so use last known data 
            
            if newtick.empty() == False and newbar.empty() == True:
                n = newtick.get()
                self.last_new_candle_data = n
                item.set_data(self.last_old_candle_data, n, self.last_time_data)
                newtick.task_done()
                
            elif newtick.empty() == True and newbar.empty() == False:
                o, t = newbar.get()
                self.last_old_candle_data = o
                self.last_time_data = t
                item.set_data(o, self.last_new_candle_data, t)
                newbar.task_done()
                
            elif newtick.empty() == False and newbar.empty() == False:                  
                n = newtick.get()
                o, t = newbar.get()
                self.last_old_candle_data = o
                self.last_new_candle_data = n
                self.last_time_data = t
   
                item.set_data(o, n, t)
                newtick.task_done()
                newbar.task_done()
                
            else:
                pass



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
item = CandlestickItem()

plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')


axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
plt.setAxisItems({"bottom": axis})

newtick = queue.Queue()
newbar = queue.Queue()

candle_type_handler = Candle_type_handler()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # window = Window()
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The unix timestamp data looks like this while running

```
[1661821590775]
[1661821590775]
[1661821590775]
[1661821590775]
[1661821590775]
[1661821590775]
[1661821616674]
[1661821616674]
[1661821616674]
[1661821616674]
[1661821616674]
[1661821616674]
```

and the price data looks like this

```
   new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]]
old bars
----------------------------------------------
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]]
old bars
----------------------------------------------
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]
 [3.      1.00013 1.00014]]
new bar
[[0.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [1.      1.00015 1.00015]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00014]
 [2.      1.00015 1.00013]
 [3.      1.00013 1.00014]
 [3.      1.00013 1.00013]]
old bars
----------------------------------------------
```

where "old bars" are the previous, static candles and "new bar" is the current active candle that has not closed yet. The "new bar" is always one bar ahead of the "old bars".

The 0,1,2, ect on the left of the rows indicate the bar number for that data and the unix array index's line up with the index in the array of the "old bars" data so it can be referenced equally.

EDIT
As requested here is a variation with static data

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np

data = np.array([  ## fields are (time, open, close, min, max).
    (1661872308774, 10, 13),
    (1661872336582, 13, 17),
    (1661872368026, 17, 14),
    (1661872397661, 14, 15),
    (1661872428131, 15, 9),
    (1661872455602, 9, 15),
    (1661872488274, 15, 5),
    (1661872518657, 5, 7),
    (1661872549187, 7, 3),
    (1661872577460, 3, 10),
    (1661872606823, 10, 15),
    (1661872639411, 15, 25),
    (1661872669708, 25, 20),
    (1661872700345, 20, 17),
    (1661872725885, 17, 30),
    (1661872760392, 30, 32),
    (1661872789563, 32, 35),
    (1661872820816, 35, 28),
    (1661872849628, 28, 27),
    (1661872880335, 27, 25),
    (1661872910454, 25, 29),
    (1661872940708, 29, 35),
    (1661872971391, 35, 40),
    (1661873001600, 40, 45),
])

class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    global data
    _boundingRect = QtCore.QRectF()


    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.flagHasData = False


    
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data 
        self.flagHasData = True
        self.generatePicture()
        self.informViewBoundsChanged()
        

    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()

        
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close) in self.data:


            rect = QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open)
            path.addRect(rect)
            
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(rect)

        p.end()
        self._boundingRect = path.boundingRect()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        if self.flagHasData:
            p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    # def boundingRect(self):
    #     return self._boundingRect
    
    def boundingRect(self):
        # data =data
        # xmin = np.nanmin(data[:,0])
        xmax = np.nanmax(data[:,0])
        xmin = xmax - 5
        ymin = np.nanmin(data[:,2])
        ymax = np.nanmax(data[:,2])
        return QtCore.QRectF(xmin, ymin, xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin)

item = CandlestickItem()
plt = pg.plot()
plt.setMouseEnabled(x=True, y=False)
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')
item.set_data(data)
axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
plt.setAxisItems({"bottom": axis})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Edit 2:

Even if I divide the unix down by 1000000 it still shows the year 9995 instead of 2022 when I zoom out.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np

data = np.array([  ## fields are (time, open, close, min, max).
    (1661872308774, 10, 13),
    (1661872336582, 13, 17),
    (1661872368026, 17, 14),
    (1661872397661, 14, 15),
    (1661872428131, 15, 9),
    (1661872455602, 9, 15),
    (1661872488274, 15, 5),
    (1661872518657, 5, 7),
    (1661872549187, 7, 3),
    (1661872577460, 3, 10),
    (1661872606823, 10, 15),
    (1661872639411, 15, 25),
    (1661872669708, 25, 20),
    (1661872700345, 20, 17),
    (1661872725885, 17, 30),
    (1661872760392, 30, 32),
    (1661872789563, 32, 35),
    (1661872820816, 35, 28),
    (1661872849628, 28, 27),
    (1661872880335, 27, 25),
    (1661872910454, 25, 29),
    (1661872940708, 29, 35),
    (1661872971391, 35, 40),
    (1661873001600, 40, 45),
])


 

 


 

 
 

class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    global data
    _boundingRect = QtCore.QRectF()


    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.flagHasData = False


    
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data 
        self.flagHasData = True
        self.generatePicture()
        self.informViewBoundsChanged()
        

    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()

        
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close) in self.data:

            time = int(t/1000000)


            print(time)

            rect = QtCore.QRectF(time-w, open, w*2, close-open)
            path.addRect(rect)
            
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(rect)

        p.end()
        self._boundingRect = path.boundingRect()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        if self.flagHasData:
            p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    # def boundingRect(self):
    #     return self._boundingRect
    
    def boundingRect(self):
        # data =data
        # xmin = np.nanmin(data[:,0])
        xmax = np.nanmax(data[:,0])
        xmin = xmax - 5
        ymin = np.nanmin(data[:,2])
        ymax = np.nanmax(data[:,2])
        return QtCore.QRectF(xmin, ymin, xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin)

item = CandlestickItem()
plt = pg.plot()
plt.setMouseEnabled(x=True, y=False)
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')
item.set_data(data)
axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
plt.setAxisItems({"bottom": axis})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a MRE with static data?

Comment: I just put placed a version with static data in the post.

Comment: Damn, even a bounty isn't enough to get this question answered. Is there not a solution?

Comment: Your timestamps look like they are (Unix timestamp)*1000. Divide by 1000 to get Unix timestamp.

Comment: As you can see in my last example, I tried that, and even tried dividing it by 1 million and it still did not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

At least in your MRE the problem is with your linux timestamps 
pyqtgraph seems to be reading the time data fine. Just your timestamps are too high in time.\

With the data below and change in the axis-range I could get this.
[image]

Data I used with MRE is

```
     (1662054508, 35, 40),
     (1662055508, 38, 43),
```

Also you may want to change the range of the axis by shifting the minimum with

```
np.nanmin(data[:,0]
or
np.nanargmax(data[:,0] - 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a way to get milisecond resolution using the timestamps I was using previously?

Comment: Make sure your dtype is float, and just divide your numbers by 1000, probably.